What’s the formula for turning a twisted edward curve into a regular or twisted Weirestrass curve back and forth?
I already have equations for converting points but what are the equations for converting the elliptic curve’s equation themsevles ? I’m espescially interested in twisted Weirestrass since quadratic twist of Weistrass curve are far more likely to produce rank 1 or rank 0 lifted curve in the Xedni calculus.

A comprehensive way to see that every nonsingular twisted Edwards curve is birationally equivalent (over an appropriate field extension) to a short Weierstrass curve can be derived by carefully pinning down algebraic transformations in affine coordinates. Concretely, consider
$$
E_{a,d}: \quad ax^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2
$$
as a twisted Edwards curve defined over a field $K$, with $a,d\neq 0$ and $a\neq d$. Let us assume $E_{a,d}$ is nonsingular, which is equivalent to the group law being well-defined (this is assured as long as $ad \neq 0$ and we avoid degenerate choices of $a,d$). We seek a short Weierstrass model
$$
\widetilde{E}: \quad Y^2 = X^3 + \alpha X + \beta
$$
for some $\alpha,\beta \in K$. To build the isomorphism, we first choose $\lambda\in K$ (or a quadratic extension of $K$ if needed) such that
$$
\lambda^2 = \frac{a}{d}.
$$
The transformation
$$
X = \frac{1 - y}{1 + y},
\quad\quad
Y = \lambda \frac{x}{1 + y}
$$
maps $(x,y)\in E_{a,d}$ to a point $(X,Y)$. When $1+y\neq 0$, these rational expressions are well-defined in $K$-affine coordinates; if $1+y=0$, we check a separate chart or projective coordinates to cover that locus.
To verify that the image $(X,Y)$ satisfies the short Weierstrass equation, we substitute:
$$
X = \frac{1-y}{1+y},
\quad\quad
Y = \lambda \frac{x}{1 + y}
$$
into the expression $Y^2 - X^3 - \alpha X - \beta$. By expanding and making repeated use of $\lambda^2=\frac{a}{d}$, and the defining relation $ax^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2$, we show that this difference simplifies identically to $0$. In other words, after suitably choosing $\alpha,\beta\in K$ as polynomial/rational functions in $a$ and $d$, the map $(x,y)\mapsto (X,Y)$ indeed lands on $\widetilde{E}$.
The inverse map $\varphi^{-1}:\widetilde{E}\to E_{a,d}$ may likewise be given by rational expressions in $X,Y$. In standard treatments, these formulae are obtained by "solving" for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$. Because both curves are cubic projective curves (and the conditions on $a,d\neq 0$ ensure nonsingularity), we obtain an explicit birational equivalence. The main considerations in practice involve choosing a convenient square root for $\lambda$ and ensuring denominators like $(1+y)$ do not vanish on too large a subset of the curve. In geometric language, twisted Edwards curves and short Weierstrass curves represent different affine charts of the same projective cubic (once the correct identification of parameters and square roots is made).

I was asking about twisted edward curve conversion. A conversion law from twisted edward to regular weirestrass indeed exist.
